# Overwrite a list value if a certain condition for another list is true (python)

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, overwrite

Unfortunately I was not able to be more specific with my title, but an example should make my problem clear. I have two lists f and a and if f[i] is equal to f[i-1]. I would like to have a new entry in f which is equal to f[i] and f[i-1] (obviously) and overwrites both of them. In a I would like to have to a_new = a[i] + a[i-1] replacing a[i] and a[i-1].

```
f = [10, 25, 50, 50, 75, 100, 1000, 1000, 1100, 1100]
a = [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 10, 15, 5, 5]
```

My desired output is:

```
f = [10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 1000, 1100]
a = [1, 3, 6, 5, 3, 25, 10]
```

I believe that some sort of list comprehension would be the optimal approach, but I couldn't figure it out yet. I doesn't need to be a list comprehension though, I am happy as long as there is some solution.

Comment: `I would like my last entry in f to be f[i]` please can you better explain what you mean?

Comment: Tried it @yatu.

Comment: I would appreciate any solution @meowgoesthedog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `zip` the lists together, use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the pairs by the `f` values, then sum the `a` values for each group.  Then you just need to unzip them back into separate lists

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

groups = groupby(zip(f, a), key=itemgetter(0))
f_a_generator = ((k, sum(map(itemgetter(1), pairs))) for k, pairs in groups)
f1, a1 = zip(*f_a_generator)  # map(list, ...) If you need them as lists

print(f1, a1, sep='\n')
# (10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 1000, 1100)
# (1, 3, 6, 5, 3, 25, 10)
```

To answer your question in the comments, you can change the line

```
sum(map(itemgetter(1), pairs)))
```

to call some function other than `sum`:

```
def logarithmic_sum(values):
    return 10*np.log10(sum((10**(val/10)) for val in values))

groups = groupby(zip(f, a), key=itemgetter(0))
f_a_generator = ((k, logarithmic_sum(map(itemgetter(1), pairs))) for k, pairs in groups)
f1, a1 = zip(*f_a_generator)

print(f1, a1, sep='\n')
# (10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 1000, 1100)
# (1.0000000000000002, 2.999999999999999, 6.124426027943397, 5.0, 2.999999999999999, 16.193310480660944, 8.010299956639813)
```

Comment: I didn't ask this originally because I didn't think it would be a problem: How could I implement logarithmic addition instead of the simple sum?
So instead of a_new = a[i] + a[i-1] I would actually like to do the following:
a_new = 10*np.log10(10** (a[i]/10) + 10** (a[i-1]/10))

Comment: @Larzeb I've edited my answer.  Basically, you need to write a function that performs that calculation, and then call it instead of `sum`

Answer (score 0):

For first array case:

```
for i in range(1, len(f)-2):
    if f[i] == f[i-1]:
        del f[i]

print(f)
```